# Angular Material Date Picker Cannot read properties of underfined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use a MatDatePicker but I keep getting really strange error you can see in the console (Screenshots below). It will not allow me to open the date picker

[Console error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCriS.png)

[Console error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYKWM.png)

Here is the code

App Module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

App Component

```js
export class AppComponent {

  // Today as default start date
  myDate = new FormControl(new Date());

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

App Component HTML

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Select a start date</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    [formControl]="myDate"
    />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-picker #picker></mat-date-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Everything renders correctly on the screen

[Correctly rendered field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE7pr.png)

Then I have those errors in the console that were linked at the start as well as when I click the date picker toggle I get the following error

[datepicker.open not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8GC.png)

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

Comment: lmao I'm so mad I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Carsten had the right answer. Had a typo

What I had

```html
<mat-date-picker #picker></mat-date-picker>
```

What it should have been

```html
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```